# How can I insert single occurrence of a duplicate name into another table?

Tags: mysql

I need to insert one of each duplicate name from one table into another.
And duplicates only.

The following query lists all duplicate names and the count:

```
select name, count(name) as cnt
from my_table
group by name
having cnt > 1
order by name
```

How can I insert one of each occurrence into another table?

**Update**

My tables are not identical.
My new table only has the following rows:

```
id (auto increment)  
name (varchar)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create table.

Then insert data to new table:

```
insert into new_table 
select name, count(name) as cnt
from my_table
group by name
having count(name) > 1
order by name
```

Consult [12.2.5.1. INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) for detailed information.

**EDITED**

You can specify columns name or order, for example:

```
insert into new_table (column1, column2)
select name, count(name) as cnt
...
```

For your table, you need to create another field to store `cnt`:

```
alter table `new_table` add column cnt int;

insert into new_table (name, cnt)
select name, count(name) as cnt
...
```

Comment: You can specify column names after the table name like `(name, name_count)` if needed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, the tables are not identical. I tried specifying columns, but then I get error message `Column count does not match value count at row 1`

Comment: You almost got it. ID has auto increment, so we can't insert there. If you remove `count(name as cnt)` from select, it works :)

Comment: @danihp Thanks. I don't store count, just the name. So your first example is correct if you remove the 'count' part in the select :)